# Optimize in each group Python

Tags: python

I tried to minimize standard deviation of column "V" for each group. So I use scipy, the code is:

This could generate a new array of "V", then I tried to apply this method for each group by using:

```
tt=df.groupby(by=["A","B"])
tt.minimize(equation,options={'xtol':0.001}).x
```

However, get an error

> 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'minimize'

Could someone gives me some advice on how to apply optimization for each group? Thanks.

Comment: groupby does not have a minimize function do you mean squeeze?

Comment: I hope to minimize std for column "V" by group. I don't know which module could be used to solve this problem. And my method only works for entire dataframe. I will search for squeeze. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `apply` method to run arbitrary Python functions on each group. `minimize` is a function in SciPy (not Pandas) and in your case, the solution will look something like this:

```py
df.groupby(by=["A","B"])\
  .apply(lambda g: minimize(equation, g.V, options={'xtol':0.001}).x)
```

Full working example:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list("abab"), 'B': list("cdcd"), 'V': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
>>> df.groupby(by=["A","B"]).apply(lambda g: minimize(rosen, g.V, options={'xtol':0.001}).x)
A  B
a  c    [0.9999955536845236, 0.9999911035369479]
b  d    [0.9999980290689747, 0.9999959871180912]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this works perfectly. As for g.V, does this mean V column in each group? and lambda g: is iterate across groups? Is my understanding right?

Comment: `lambda` is Python syntax for quickly creating functions. `apply` method takes in any function whose first argument is a dataframe and calls this function & returns the result for each group. Yes, `g` is a group / dataframe and g.V refers to its column.

Comment: Make sense. Thank you for your kind reply!